# Viewpage-like control, but in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, android-viewpager, desktop

I would like to implements something like android ViewPager, but in WinForms.
I want it to behave exactly the same (including swipe to change page).

What would be the best way to go about this?

Comment: This is a very broad question, could you tackle this functionality by functionality trying it out and then showing us what you have when you struggle so we can assist.

Comment: winforms is not the appropriate technology for this (nor anything else I can think of). It doesn't have built in support for animations, transitions, or touch events, all of which are required for what you're trying to do. Use either WPF or WinRT XAML instead.

Comment: @ThulaniChivandikwa ok, will try to do it like you suggested.

Comment: @HighCore since I'm working on a winforms project I will try to do it with winforms and switch to WPF only if it not possible in winforms.

Comment: @user3759320 Good luck. When your UI becomes totally unusable due to constant flickering caused by lack of hardware acceleration you'll realize you need to use modern technology instead.